# Finding a stationary distribution for a transition matrix with not quite diagonal elements.

Tags: markov-chains, stationary-processes, transition-matrix

Consider a Markov chain on the nonnegative integers with transition
matrix $\mathbf{P}$ given by $P_{i,i+1}=p$ and $P_{i,0}=1-p$ for all $i$, and for
some $0<p<1$.  Find a stationary distribution $\vec{\pi}$.  Is it unique?

I know this is an irreducible transition matrix so it has a unique stationary distribution. I have tried creating a system of equations but that does not get me anywhere and have looked at finding the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1):

The $i$th row of $P$ looks like $\begin{bmatrix} 1-p & 0 & 0 & \dots & p & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, where the $p$ is the $i+1$ position. The $i$th column then looks like $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \dots \\ p \\ 0 \\ \dots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ where now the $p$ is in the $i-1$ position, for $i>0$; for $i=0$ all the entries of the column are $1-p$. So the equations for the stationary distribution, for $i>0$, are $\pi_i=p \pi_{i-1}$. This equation is very simple to solve for a solution which involves $\pi_0$. You can then select $\pi_0$ based on the normalization condition to finish the problem.